# Calling a javascript function from a href

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, alert

Hi Im trying to call a javascript function from within a div function

Bascially I have a filter box which adds a bootstrap alert to a textbox and this works perfectly, the issue is when I click the close button on the alert it is not running the specified function and i dont know why

This is the routine which adds the alert to the text box, in it I specify the javascript function to run and 3 variables. the function clear does not seem to get called

```
//Add Filter on " Add Filters" button click
$("#filter2-add").click(function(){
           table.addFilter($("#filter2-field").val(), $("#filter2-type").val(), $("#filter2-value").val());

         var div = document.getElementById('appliedfilters');
           div.innerHTML += '<div id="'+$("#filter2-field").val()+$("#filter2-value").val()+'" style="width:500px; height:20px;text-align: left;display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;line-height: normal;" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><a href="javascript:clear(\''+$("#filter2-field").val()+'\',\''+$("#filter2-type").val().charCodeAt(0)+'\',\''+$("#filter2-value").val()+'\')"; class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Filter  </strong>'+$("#filter2-field").val()+' '+$("#filter2-type").val()+' '+$("#filter2-value").val()+'</div>';
            });
```

Comment: Essential information is missing from your question, while there's tons of irrelevant stuff. Briefly, `javascript:functionName()` will call the function named `functionName` that is defined in the global scope - can confirm that it works. In your code, where is the definition of `clear`? Please edit your question by removing everything that does not influence the behaviour that you are seeing, format the code and include enough code so that the definition of function `clear` is visible, otherwise it's not possible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code has a syntax error.
Try replacing

```
div.innerHTML += '<div id="'+$("#filter2-field").val()+$("#filter2-value").val()+'" style="width:500px; height:20px;text-align: left;display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;line-height: normal;" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><a href="javascript:clear(\''+$("#filter2-field").val()+'\',\''+$("#filter2-type").val().charCodeAt(0)+'\',\''+$("#filter2-value").val()+'\')"; class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Filter  </strong>'+$("#filter2-field").val()+' '+$("#filter2-type").val()+' '+$("#filter2-value").val()+'</div>';
```

with

```
div.innerHTML += '<div id="'+$("#filter2-field").val()+$("#filter2-value").val()+'" style="width:500px; height:20px;text-align: left;display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;line-height: normal;" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><a href="javascript:clear(\''+$("#filter2-field").val()+'\',\''+$("#filter2-type").val().charCodeAt(0)+'\',\''+$("#filter2-value").val()+'\');" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Filter  </strong>'+$("#filter2-field").val()+' '+$("#filter2-type").val()+' '+$("#filter2-value").val()+'</div>';
```

Comment: Tom thank you so much, ive spent hours on that and you have fixed it in 8 mins